# Arrange a dataset based on a column , then return rows indices

Tags: r, tidyverse

Good afternoon!

Assume we have the following dataset :

```
Centers = structure(list(X5 = c(5, 2, 6, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5), 
    X1 = c(4, 1, 1, 6, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1), X1.1 = c(4, 
    1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1), X1.2 = c(5, 1, 1, 6, 
    8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 3, 1, 6), X2 = c(7, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 
    4, 10, 1, 6, 1, 3, 3), X1.3 = c(10, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
    3, 10, 3, 1, 1), X3 = c(3, 1, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 
    1, 1), X1.4 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    X1.5 = c(1, 5, 1, 1, 10, 10, 1, 1, 7, 4, 1, 1, 1), X2.1 = c(2, 
    2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(1L, 8L, 
19L, 41L, 69L, 83L, 116L, 127L, 158L, 347L, 470L, 505L, 569L), class = "data.frame")

centers data : 
        X5 X1 X1.1 X1.2 X2 X1.3 X3 X1.4 X1.5 X2.1
    1    5  4    4    5  7   10  3    2    1    2
    8    2  1    1    1  2    1  1    1    5    2
    19   6  1    1    1  2    1  3    1    1    2
    41   5  6    5    6 10    1  3    1    1    4
    69   6 10    2    8 10    2  7    8   10    4
    83   5 10    6    1 10    4  4   10   10    4
    116  1  1    1    1  4    3  1    1    1    2
    127  1  1    1    1 10    1  1    1    1    2
    158  1  1    1    2  1    3  1    1    7    2
    347  3 10    3   10  6   10  5    1    4    4
    470  1  1    1    3  1    3  1    1    1    2
    505  1  1    1    1  3    1  1    1    1    2
    569  5  1    1    6  3    1  1    1    1    2
```

I'm searching a way to `arrange` this dataframe `based on the last column X2.1`.

Arranged data :

```
df <- Centers[order(Centers[, ncol(Centers)]), ]

df 
#     X5 X1 X1.1 X1.2 X2 X1.3 X3 X1.4 X1.5 X2.1
# 1    5  4    4    5  7   10  3    2    1    2
# 8    2  1    1    1  2    1  1    1    5    2
# 19   6  1    1    1  2    1  3    1    1    2
# 116  1  1    1    1  4    3  1    1    1    2
# 127  1  1    1    1 10    1  1    1    1    2
# 158  1  1    1    2  1    3  1    1    7    2
# 470  1  1    1    3  1    3  1    1    1    2
# 505  1  1    1    1  3    1  1    1    1    2
# 569  5  1    1    6  3    1  1    1    1    2
# 41   5  6    5    6 10    1  3    1    1    4
# 69   6 10    2    8 10    2  7    8   10    4
# 83   5 10    6    1 10    4  4   10   10    4
# 347  3 10    3   10  6   10  5    1    4    4
```

After that , I need to retrieve the following `list` output :

```
list1=list(c(1,8,19,116,127,158,470,505,569),c(41,69,83,347))
```

**This output changes according to the used dataset. ( For clarity , I'm wanting to retrieve this list as an output , I'm not interested on subsetting rows associated to those indices)**

I hope my question is clear !

Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: So you want to order your entire `data.frame()` by the last column and then obtain the rows you specified in a `list()`?

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R , excactly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
split(rownames(df), df$X2.1)
#split(rownames(Centers), Centers$X2.1) #Alternative
#$`2`
#[1] "1"   "8"   "19"  "116" "127" "158" "470" "505" "569"
#
#$`4`
#[1] "41"  "69"  "83"  "347"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some efforts , we could use this solution :

```
library(tidyverse)


 df <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(25),
  y=rnorm(25),
  g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)

print(df)

X <- split(df, df$g) #split dataframe by groups
str(X)

print(X)
print(lapply(X,rownames)) # print a list of desired rownames
```